# python: boolean array to polygon

Tags: python, shapely

I have a boolean array with one connected component of `True` values, the border of which I would like to convert to a polygon, e.g. in shapely.

Assuming my array is `img`, I can get the border indices like this

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology binary_erosion

border_indices = np.transpose(np.nonzero(np.logical_xor(binary_erosion(img), img)))
```

but just feeding those into a `shapely.Polygon` object does not work because the points are not ordered along the boundary, but in increasing `x` and `y` values.

It may be possible to use alpha shapes to solve this (note that I'm not looking for the convex hull), but maybe someone can suggest a simpler way of getting to the bounding polygon, ideally directly operating on the original array.

Comment: Could you please add a concrete example of `border_indices` to better understand the question.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like `rasterio.features.shapes` is what you are looking for. A simple example that should illustrate the procedure:

```
import rasterio.features
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np

im = np.zeros([5, 5], dtype=np.uint8)
im[1:-1, 1:-1] = 1

shapes = rasterio.features.shapes(im)
```

`shapes` is a generator with pairs of (geometry, value). To get the geometry corresponding to where the value is equal to 1:

```
polygons = [shapely.geometry.Polygon(shape[0]["coordinates"][0]) for shape in shapes if shape[1] == 1]
```

This creates a list of `shapely` polygons corresponding to the areas in the array where the value is equal to 1.

```
print(polygons)
[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7f64bf9ac9e8>]
```